# Dependency injection and the observer pattern

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, observer-pattern

I find that fairly frequently in my code I do this (using Guice as my DI framework):

```
public class SomeObserver implements IObserver {
    @Inject
    SomeObserver(IObservable observable) {
        observable.subscribe(this);
    }
    // Snip
}
```

It occurred to me recently that, when testing, I am now required to pass at least a mock into my program, which is not necessarily the worst thing, but it does depend on at least binding a dependency to that `IObservable` interface. Another option would be to, in production, do this:

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {
    // snip

    @Provides
    protected SomeObserver provideSomeObserver(IObservable observable) {
        SomeObserver newObject = new SomeObserver();
        newObject.subscribe(observable);
    }
}
```

Then in testing, I don't have to even have a reference to the `Observable`. However, if I ever want to change the constructor, the module must change as well (which it doesn't in the first example).

Which is better? Or is there an even better third option?

---

Update: I want to talk about my use case a bit.

Consider a data processing application, where a data source is the Observable. I don't want the data source to know about other parts of the system ([Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). The data is filtered into at least three different Observers, who work on independent tasks. I want to keep the data source swappable - for testing, separation of concerns, etc. reasons, so the data source just implements what I've defined to be a `Subscribable<Observer>` interface, and then you can just call `.subscribe(this)`.

Then, I use dependency injection and modules to determine exactly how the wiring is going to be. This solution also allows me to [decorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) observables if I choose, using annotations to clarify the injections.

So, essentially, I'm using Dependency Injection to manage the wiring, which is exactly what I originally thought it was for; creating, say, an `ObservationManager` seems like a lot of [boilerplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) for little gain. But again, I may be missing something.

Comment: How about an event bus?

Comment: @condit Same problem, then I need to mock the event bus or at least create a reference to it. Which is not relevant if I'm passing the messages in manually in a test case.

Comment: You could still use a real instance of the event bus in your tests. With Guava's `EventBus`, this is as simple as instantiating a new one per test (or test suite if you'd like), and using `EventBus.post` instead of passing it in the constructor (or provider in your 2nd example).

Comment: @moofins: I actually was using [`MBassador`](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador), which is [a LOT faster than `EventBus`](http://codeblock.engio.net/37/), but unfortunately not fast enough in this bit of code.

Comment: In that case, I would say that your first approach is totally fine. DI can do so much more than just wire up collaborators. Just look at Guice's `ServletModule`; it's using injection to wire anything from filters to request-scoped query parameters.

Comment: @moofins I use DI for a lot more things, I just wasn't talking about them in this post :)

Comment: Yeah I figured as much :). My comment was mostly an affirmation that, in fact, you aren't missing anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're kind of misusing dependency injection.

Dependency injection, as its name suggests, intends to resolve a problem with resolving class dependencies. But semantically observer and observable are not dependent on each other. They really should not be treated as dependencies.

Setting up observer-observable relationship is a separate task by itself, so ideally you should have a third entity which depends on observer and observable and sets up a relationship between them. Using event bus looks pretty orthogonal in this case because it still boils down to subscription, and subscription should be done somewhere.

In fact that you have noticed that it is weird to use mocks in this case is a signal that you're trying to use as a dependency something which is not a dependency at all. For normal dependencies (which are used by the class directly) it is perfectly OK to provide mock objects, they're intended exactly for that after all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated a bit more about my use case to make the problem more clear. Btw, I agree that using an event bus is orthogonal to the problem.

Comment: @durron597, no, creating what you called `ObservableManager` is not boilerplate. Boilerplate means that you have to write lots of code to get little result. But in this case you will just move the logic from constructors to separate class. There is no extra code aside class definition, so I wouldn't call that boilerplate. This is in fact a separation of concerns. Moreover, with central place to configure observer subscriptions, obviously, you have single place to look for them. In your current design these subscriptions are spread over the whole codebase.